# I need to access the internal sotorage

Tags: samsung, rom

I was changing the ROM on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S5 SM G900P) when I deleted the OS. Now I know I can flash a new one by adding a zip file to the SD card or Internal storage.

The problem is that I can access either one of those since all i can go into is recovery and download which doesn't enable the usage of File transfers via USB. I need to know some way for me to get access to the storage, any help is welcomed.

Comment: Nothing enables the usage of files transfer *via USB charger* (unless you're talking about badUSB)!

Comment: Does your S5 have a custom recovery, so you can flash any ROM from there? Then you could use `adb push` (see [adb tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info)) while booted into recovery. Alternatively, as it's a Samsung device, take a look at our [odin](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/odin/info) and [heimdall](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/heimdall/info) tag-wikis. AFAIK those tools can be used to flash ROMs with the device in download mode.

Comment: @Firelord you're an evil guy :) Don't recommend such "uploads" :)

Answer (score 0):

In this you have one option of **sideload in recovery**. In this case you need custom recovery. If you don't have a custom recovery them you need to flash it using odin in download.
Now boot in recovery mode. Go to install > Install from sideload (in cwm) or advance > sideload (in twrp).
Now when you open it, open terminal / command prompt. Type command 
`adb sideload your_rom.zip`

It may seem that nothing is happening. You must have to **wait** and don't touch usb until work is done. Any interruption may hard brick your device. Even though it is safe.

> For this you must have **required adb tools** ( for this you can search ).

Comment: Please use quote tag (>) only when you're citing something from somewhere.